# English equivalent for 'hungry of eyes', which describes someone who takes more food than they can eat

Tags: idiom-requests, translation

There is an Urdu idiom, آنکھوں کا بھوکا, which literally translates to **hungry of eyes**.

It's used to describe *someone who takes more food than they can eat- someone's who's greedy.*

For example, we might say that *Ali is hungry of eyes*.

How would I say that in English?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could say *his eyes are bigger than his stomach*.

> **Somebody's eyes are bigger than their belly/stomach:**
> something that you say when someone has taken more food than they can eat.

[[Cambridge English dictionary]](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/sb-s-eyes-are-bigger-than-their-belly-stomach)

Example: Ali's eyes are bigger than his stomach.

Answer (score 7):

In Glasgow we say: **"Ali, ya eyne is bigger then ya belly!"**

My Pakistani friends use it too, although they speak as much Urdu as English, well Scot's Urdo at this point. :)

Answer (score 7):

@DecapitatedSoul has already provided the best possible answer, but I'll still offer up **bite off more than one can chew**. From M-W:

> **[bite off more than one can chew](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bite%20off%20more%20than%20he%20can%20chew)**: to undertake more than one can handle

This applies to virtually any activity, including eating. In the latter case, it is a bit of a *double entendre*. I have often used it myself when I've ordered or taken more food than I can eat. It works well served with a wry smile.

Comment: Ironically, it's seldom used to actually talk about food

Comment: @Kevin It is ironic, but I have often used it myself when I've ordered or taken more food than I can eat.It works well served with a wry smile.

Comment: The original example implied greed and (to an extent) hoarding, but I've only heard this particular idiom used to denote over-confidence or getting onseself into a situation where they cannot succeed.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The original example implied greed only in the limited sense of taking more food than one can eat. No implication of hoarding except in the limited sense of one-off monopolization of food offerings. I agree that *biting off more than one can chew* usually denotes taking on more than one can handle, but that can certainly apply to eating, too. And then, as I said, *biting off more than one can chew* results in an amusing double entendre.